# decompile the jar, some source code are marked as red(which means mistake)

Tags: java, jar, decompiler

Android Studio decompile the jar, some source code are marked as red which seems means there is mistacke,usually is cant resolve symol xxx
This situation occurs in my android.jar and java jdk.
I guess it is because decompile, so it is not pure source code.But i found some used import package are not exist..
Fox example, in package java.util.concurrent.atomic;
the AtomicInteger.java import sun.misc.Unsafe.
But there is not sun's pacakge after my search in my lib.
I think this question is not too much benefit to my programming skill, but i just cant figure out the internal principle in using java jar lib.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Use Intellij 12+ decompiler instead. I haven't seen any decompiler like the one used in intellij.

Good Luck.